# How C++ call Fortran 77's common blocks

Tags: c++, gcc, fortran, gfortran, fortran-common-block

I am a fresh in programming and I want to call a Fortran 77 common block in my C++ code. Actually I have read some Q&A similar like mine, but I was not very clear....

This common block is defined by another Fortran 77 subroutine.

Sample code is:

common.inc:

```
!test common block:
real delta(5,5)
common /test/ delta
!save /test/ delta  ! any differences if I comment this line?
```

tstfunc.f

```
subroutine tstfunc()
    implicit none
    include 'common.inc'
    integer i,j
    do i = 1, 5
        do j = 1, 5
            delta(i,j)=2
            if(i.ne.j) delta(i,j)=0
            write (*,*) delta(i,j)
        end do
    end do
end
```

tst01.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    void tstfunc_();
};

void printmtrx(float (&a)[5][5]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
            std::cout<<a[j][i]<<'\t';
            a[j][i]+=2;
        }
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
//start...
    tstfunc_();
    printmtrx(delta);//here i want to call delta and manipulate it. 
    return 0;
}
```

If I want to pass `delta` (from common.inc) to the C++ function `printmtrx()`, what should I do?

Comment: This is compiler-dependent. Which compilers do you use?

Comment: Dear @MSalters,  I use gfortran and g++

Comment: You don't call common blocks. They contain data, not code. 'What should I do this?' is not an intelligible question, and there is no evidence of an actual problem here. What you're asking remains unclear.

Comment: Thanks @EJP I updated my Question

Comment: But not your title, and there is still no evidence of a problem.

Comment: @francescalus good point - I had looked at the number of questions tagged (only 43 for `fortran-common-block`) but I agree it's more important than `fortran77`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the row/column-major order issue (the 5x5 matrix would appear transposed in the C-code), perhaps you could proceed as follows (see section on Common blocks in this [tutorial](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialMixingFortranAndC.html)):

tstfunc1.f

```
  subroutine tstfunc()
      implicit none
      real delta(5, 5)
      common /test/ delta
      integer i,j
      do i = 1, 5
          do j = 1, 5
              delta(i,j)=2
              if(i.ne.j) delta(i,j)=0
              write (*,*) delta(i,j)
          end do
      end do
  end
```

tst01.cc

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
  void tstfunc_();
  extern struct{
    float data[5][5];
  } test_;
}

void printmtrx(float (&a)[5][5]){
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
          std::cout << a[i][j] << '\t';
          a[i][j] += 2;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
 }

int main()
{
  //start...
  tstfunc_();

  printmtrx(test_.data);//here i want to call delta and manipulate it. 
  return 0;
}
```

Then in order to compile:

```
gfortran -c -o tstfunc1.o tstfunc1.f    
g++ -o tst tst01.cc tstfunc1.o -lgfortran
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that 2D arrays in C are [row-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) whereas in FORTRAN they are [column-major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-major_order), so you need to switch your array indices in one language or the other.